# Logo or Button a side of tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tab, lightning-tabset

Is it possible to add a logo ,an Icon or a button on a side of the tabs , just here :
[image]

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabset/example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to do so. You would need to create your own custom tabset component (via [SLDS documentation](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#site-main-content)) and modify it from there. There is no built-in model that includes such a feature, so it may look unusual to viewers. That said, you could use position: absolute CSS and position whatever you'd like to overlay the corner, but it would not be part of the component itself.